# Unable to open "File" or "Edit" menu in Notepad using WinAppDriver

Tags: nunit, winappdriver, appium-desktop

I'm trying to learn how to use WinAppDriver to test my desktop app developed in VS2019.

I'm able to run a NUnit test using the basic Notepad.exe and example of typing text. However, I'm unable to click on menu elements in Notepad for example. How do you achieve this?

Inspect.exe says its name is "Edit".

I'm using the Appium.WebDriver 4.1.1 nuget package.

Here is a good example of what I'm trying to do, but the code is outdated: https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Samples/C%23/NotepadTest/ScenarioMenuItem.cs

**Test Code in VS2019**

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
using System;

namespace Notepad_Tests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> NotepadSession;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var appiumOptions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumOptions();
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", @"Windows");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", @"WindowsPC");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"C:\Windows\notepad.exe");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"C:\Windows\notepad.exe");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appArguments", @"MyTestFile.txt");
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appWorkingDir", @"D:\MyTestFolder\");
            NotepadSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appiumOptions);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            NotepadSession.FindElementByClassName("Edit").SendKeys("This is some text");
            NotepadSession.FindElementByName("Edit").Click();
        }
        [TearDown]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            // NotepadSession.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error in WinAppDriver.exe window**

```
==========================================
POST /session HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 236
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)

{"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Windows","deviceName":"WindowsPC","app":"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe","appArguments":"MyTestFile.txt","appWorkingDir":"D:\\MyTestFolder\\"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Windows"}]}}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 200
Content-Type: application/json

{"sessionId":"431F0707-71BD-4645-B085-5BD750FC2067","status":0,"value":{"app":"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe","appArguments":"MyTestFile.txt","appWorkingDir":"D:\\MyTestFolder\\","platformName":"Windows"}}


==========================================
POST /session/431F0707-71BD-4645-B085-5BD750FC2067/element HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 37
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)

{"using":"class name","value":"Edit"}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 96
Content-Type: application/json

{"sessionId":"431F0707-71BD-4645-B085-5BD750FC2067","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"42.2099874"}}


==========================================
POST /session/431F0707-71BD-4645-B085-5BD750FC2067/element/42.2099874/value HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)

{"value":["This is some text"]}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 63
Content-Type: application/json

{"sessionId":"431F0707-71BD-4645-B085-5BD750FC2067","status":0}

==========================================
POST /session/431F0707-71BD-4645-B085-5BD750FC2067/element HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)

{"using":"name","value":"Edit"}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 128
Content-Type: application/json

{"sessionId":"431F0707-71BD-4645-B085-5BD750FC2067","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"42.3148312.3.-2147483646.27904.691604525.2"}}


==========================================
POST /session/431F0707-71BD-4645-B085-5BD750FC2067/element/42.3148312.3.-2147483646.27904.691604525.2/click HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)

{}
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":105,"value":{"error":"element not interactable","message":"An element command could not be completed because the element is not pointer- or keyboard interactable."}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using the Microsoft.WinAppDriver.Appium.WebDriver Prerlease nugget package instead of the  Appium.WebDriver 4.1.1 nuget package.

Then, the example here works perfectly:

https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Samples/C%23/NotepadTest/ScenarioMenuItem.cs